# Animated crossproduct?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, tikz-arrows

How can I make this animation using latex?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Of course, you can make similar animation with LaTeX. With lot of effort. In it probably will be handy `animate` package ...

Comment: You can get some ideas from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303331/drawing-an-animated-circle-in-latex/303427#303427

Comment: Would you be able to pick up from a starting point? Like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wOfmY.gif

Comment: I think I would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here's a starting point, I think it has all you need to progress. If you don't know how to do something specific, you could ask a new question, but  if it's just a doubt on the code I'm providing, you can post a comment.

There's a tiny flaw where the drawing "moves" in a certain frame, but I'm not sure what's causing it. Will fix it as soon as I understand what is going on.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\basicstuff{
    \path (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\dirz.5);
    \path (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-\dirz.5);
}
\newcommand\dd{
    \textcolor{gray}{\|}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro\dirx{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\diry{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dirz{3}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\foreach \angle [
    evaluate=\angle as \zz using (\angle/30),
    evaluate=\angle as \opac using (\angle/50),
    ] in {0,5,...,90}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\basicstuff

\begin{scope}[opacity=\opac]
\filldraw[draw=orange, fill=orange!30] (0,0,.5) --++ (\angle:.5) --++ (0,0,-.5) -- (0,0,0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[draw=orange, fill=orange!30] (0,0,.5) --++ (0:.5) --++ (0,0,-.5) -- (0,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\draw[thick, blue,-{Latex}] (0,0,0) -- (0:\dirx);
\draw[thick, red, -{Latex}] (0,0,0) -- (\angle:\diry);
\ifnum\angle>5
\draw[thick, violet, -{Latex}] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\zz);
\else\fi
\draw (0,0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);

\fill (0,0,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \opac using (\x/10)] in {0,...,10,10,10,10,10,10}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\basicstuff

\filldraw[draw=orange, fill=orange!30] (0,0,.5) --++ (90:.5) --++ (0,0,-.5) -- (0,0,0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[draw=orange, fill=orange!30] (0,0,.5) --++ (0:.5) --++ (0,0,-.5) -- (0,0,0) -- cycle;

\draw[thick, blue,-{Latex}] (0,0,0) -- (0:\dirx);
\draw[thick, red, -{Latex}] (0,0,0) -- (90:\diry);
\draw[thick, violet, -{Latex}] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\dirz);
\draw (0,0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);

\begin{scope}[opacity=\opac]
\node[below,text width=4.5cm, font=\Large\bfseries, text centered, anchor=north] at (0,0,-1.5) {
    $\textcolor{blue}{a} \textcolor{orange}{\perp} \textcolor{red}{b}$\\
    $\dd \textcolor{violet}{a \times b} \dd = \dd\textcolor{blue}{a}\dd \dd\textcolor{red}{b}\dd$
    };
\end{scope}

\fill (0,0,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have  a question. Do you know how to view gif file? Is opening in a browser the only way?

Comment: @user Ah sorry, you need to have ImageMagick, then open Terminal and go to the directory where your document is located, then type `convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 300 -scale 400 -alpha remove <file>.pdf <file>.gif`

Comment: I can convert to gif. But after having gif file what is the best way to show gif.

Comment: @user it depends on your os. But sure,  the browser is one way. :)

Comment: What are the other ways. I have mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. Is there  a more elegant way?

Comment: @user if you have Mac,  then select the gif file and press spacebar.  That supports gifs. :) it's what I use.

Comment: A lot of thanks. It works and it is more elegant than browser.