# animated proof in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

How can I  make something like this? I would prefer tikz. [image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/is-there-any-way-to-include-an-animated-gif-directly

Comment: Not exactly. I am not thinking to include it in pdf. I want to make it using latex, tikz.

Comment: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303506/1952

Comment: To the downvoter: especially with new users, I think it is wise to leave a comment explaining why you think that this question isn’t a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty elaborate animation, so here's a start. If you have trouble (and probably you will), feel free to ask a new question, but remember to keep it focused on a specific issue you got stuck with.

Adding `tikz` to the `standalone` class options allows your pdf to have one page per frame.

To compile this as a .gif, install [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) in your system, then do this in your Terminal/Command Prompt:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 300 -scale 400 -alpha remove file.pdf file.gif
```

where `file.pdf` is the name of your file and `file.gif` is the name of the resulting .gif file, change the name accordingly.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\newcommand\basicstuff{
    \path (-5,-3) rectangle (5,3);
}

\tikzset{
    bas/.style={text width=4cm}
}

\begin{document}\Huge
\foreach \x in {0,...,10}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\basicstuff

\node[bas] at (0,3) {$\textcolor{red}{ax^2} + \textcolor{green}{bx} + \textcolor{blue}{c}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\foreach \x [
    count=\xx starting from 0, 
    evaluate=\x as \opac using (\x/10),
    evaluate=\x as \y using (3-\x)
    ] in {0,.25,...,2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\basicstuff

\node[bas] at (0,3) {$\textcolor{red}{ax^2} + \textcolor{green}{bx} + \textcolor{blue}{c}$};

\node[bas, opacity=\opac] at (-\x,\y) {$\textcolor{red}{axx}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\basicstuff

\node[bas] at (0,3) {$\textcolor{red}{ax^2} + \textcolor{green}{bx} + \textcolor{blue}{c}$};

\node[bas] at (-2,1) {$\textcolor{red}{axx}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\foreach \y [
    count=\xx starting from 0,
    evaluate=\xx as \xi using (-2.75-(.25*-\xx*1.5)),
    evaluate=\xx as \yi using (.8-(.25*\xx*2.5)),
    evaluate=\y as \x using (1-\y)
    ] in {1,.8,...,0}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\basicstuff

\node[bas] at (0,3) {$\textcolor{red}{ax^2} + \textcolor{green}{bx} + \textcolor{blue}{c}$};

\filldraw[draw=red, fill=red!50] (-2.75,.6) rectangle (\xi,\yi);
\path (-2.75,.8) -- (-2.75,\yi) node[left, midway] {$\textcolor{red}{ax}$};
\path (-2.75,.5) -- (\xi,.5) node[above, midway] {$\textcolor{red}{x}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\basicstuff

\node[bas] at (0,3) {$\textcolor{red}{ax^2} + \textcolor{green}{bx} + \textcolor{blue}{c}$};

\filldraw[draw=red, fill=red!50] (-2.75,.6) rectangle (-.875,-2.325);
\path (-2.75,.8) -- (-2.75,-2.325) node[left, midway] {$\textcolor{red}{ax}$};
\path (-2.75,.5) -- (-.875,.5) node[above, midway] {$\textcolor{red}{x}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you are so helpful :-) Because of you I can make some beautiful animations for my class.

Comment: Why gif? I would use the animate package. (But I don't like such animations, I prefer when such explanation don't move so that I can study them at my pace).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It depends on the medium I suppose, but I totally see where you're coming from. I think that "animations" as in, animated transactions from one state to another, are nice to see in a presentation when the teacher is explaining. Or for example if the animation is relevant for the topic (i.e. physics class). I find the animate package to be a bit arduous to use. :P

Comment: As you are drawing the pictures with tikz anyway, you only need to insert \newframe at suitable places.

Comment: How does it work with animation adding \newframe. It might be useful for my student, since gif is too quick for some of them?

Comment: @Alenanno : Just want to understand your comment, what does *arduous* mean; cannot find it in my dict.

Comment: @AlexG it means tough, difficult, hard. :)

Comment: @Alenanno : Oh, really? Just include your PDF with `\animategraphics[controls]{20}{file}{}{}` .

Comment: @Alenanno Will you please tell me how have you calculated the following:       evaluate=\xx as \xi using (-2.75-(.25*-\xx*1.5)),
    evaluate=\xx as \yi using (.8-(.25*\xx*2.5)),
    evaluate=\y as \x using (1-\y)
    ] in {1,.8,...,0}{

Comment: Does anyone have a finished product for the entire animation?